# Gravar em um arquivo csv com JSP sem sobrescrever o que já tem

Tags: jsp, csv

Tenho esse código abaixo para gravar uma informação no arquivo csv, mas sempre que eu gravo algo, o que já tinha escrito é perdido. Como faço pra ele adicionar uma linha com a nova informação mantendo o que já tem?

```
String fName = "cadastros.csv";
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fName);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fos);
pw.println(request.getParameter("nome") + ";" + request.getParameter("email"));
pw.close();
fos.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Leia o arquivo em uma string, adicione o novo conteudo nessa string e depois grava a string com o antigo e o novo conteudo.